# Problems with Array Treatment

Tags: node.js

I need help :)

I'm trying to get an array like this:

```
['XSRF-TOKEN=advlqegqeozvqqeax; Max-Age=259200; Expires=Mon, 09-jul-2011 22:28:41 GMT; Path=/',
  'JWT-SESSION=qefqefoizxivhiohqdiovhoiqeioghqehoghioqe; Max-Age=259200; Expires=Wed, 13-jul-2011 22:28:41 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly' ]
```

and put like this way:

```
XSRF-TOKEN=advlqegqeozvqqeax; JWT-SESSION=qefqefoizxivhiohqdiovhoiqeioghqehoghioqe;
```

but i'm new at NodeJS and i'm trying to learn,

can you guys help me? I'm stuck in this for a long time :(

Thansk a lot

Comment: Please provide what you are trying and where you are getting the issue, we cant help you with the info you provided here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write something like that:

```
const array = [
'XSRF-TOKEN=advlqegqeozvqqeax; Max-Age=259200; Expires=Mon, 09-jul-2011 22:28:41 GMT; Path=/', 
'JWT-SESSION=qefqefoizxivhiohqdiovhoiqeioghqehoghioqe; Max-Age=259200; Expires=Wed, 13-jul-2011 22:28:41 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly' 
]

const result = array.map( properties => properties.split(';')[0] ).join(';')

console.log(result);
```

Here the functions i used:

- [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)